# Getting bidimensionnal preset array out of an class

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to use a bidimensionnal array - where i store values as a preset - out of my class.
Here is my class :

```
public class preset 
{
  double arrayPreset[][] = {
                            {
                              // First dimension of array (x values)
                              3.5, 4.0, 4.5, 5.0, 5.5, 6.0, 6.5, 7.0, 7.5, 8.0, 8.5, 9.0, 9.5, 10.0, 10.5, 
                              11.0, 11.5, 12.0, 12.5, 13.0, 13.5, 14.0, 14.5, 15.0, 15.5, 16.0, 16.5, 17.0, 
                              17.5, 18.0,18.5, 19.0, 19.5, 20.0
                            }, 
                            {
                              // Second dimension of array (y values)
                              34, 88, 155, 237, 333, 448, 582,738, 919, 1123, 1351,1604, 1845, 2043, 2200, 
                              2321, 2409, 2467, 2495, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 
                              2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500, 2500
                            } 
                            };

 public double[][] getArray()
 {
   return this.arrayPreset;
 }
  public preset()
 {
 }
}
```

And here is my call :

```
preset defaultPreset = null;

// ERROR
double presetCurve[][] = defaultPreset.getArray();

System.out.println("Get preset");

for(double m = 0.5; m < presetCurve.length; m += 0.5)
{
 System.out.println("m = " +m);
}
```

My aim is to display if the different values are stocked correctly so that i can parse the array easily.
Final goal is to use arrayPreset[x][y] for the point value at x, value at y in a plot.

What am i doing wrong ?

The error message i've got is :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at IOControl.ReadCSV.run(ReadCSV.java:366) // which is line tagged with a "ERROR" as comment
    at en.window.Main.main(Main.java:46)
```

Thanks for the time :)

Comment: you aren't initializing the preset class - its set to null and will return null - try preset defaultPreset = new preset();

Comment: just to mention the obvious,  you initialize `arrayPreset` and return `arrayN100`. You are accessing the array in an static way, so you should declare it `static` as well.

Comment: You have assigned the reference to `null` just one line above. Please at least try to figure out what's the issue with your code. Use a debugger. You will possibly get these kinds of issues resolved with that.

Comment: Consider to follow Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
defaultPreset.getArray();
```

Here `defaultPreset` is null, which actually become `null.getArray()` cause this `NullPointerException`.

You need to create `preset Object` -

```
preset defaultPreset = new preset();
```

Comment: That's right... can't believe i didn't saw that straight away :o
I thought the problem was somehow with the filling of the array.
Thanks !